# Prove $f$ is surjective or not

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> For $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, prove/disprove $f(x) = x^2 + 4x + 9$ is surjective.

I say it is not surjective. Let $y = 0$ then the discriminant of $f(x)$ is $16 - 36 < 0$, thus $x \not \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is this the correct way to go about it?

Comment: You mean to say that there is no $x\in\Bbb R$ with $f(x)=0$. ... Even better, you could complete the square (or use calculus) and show precisely what values the function takes on. But finding one single $y$ that fails to be a value of the function is all you need to show the function is not surjective.

Comment: Your answer seems perfectly fine.
More generally any polynomial of even degree goes to infinity on  $\infty$ and $-\infty$, and since a polynomial is always continuous, it is not surjective.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2 + 4x + 9 = (x+2)^2 + 5$ thus your function only takes value in $[5, +\infty[$ and is therefore not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Showing the function has no real roots (which you can do with the discriminant) means that $0$ is not in the range, so the function is not surjective.

However, this wouldn't work for all quadratics, since some of them have real roots, but none are surjective.

---

Alternatively, using the derivative, $f'(x) = 2x + 4$, the function has a minimum at $x = -2$.

$$f(-2) = (-2)^2 + 4(-2) + 9 = 5$$

Thus $f(x) \ge 5$ implies the function is not surjective.

**Edit:** Without calculus you can still see that $5$ is the minimum value by completing the square: $$f(x) = (x+2)^2 + 5$$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it is not surjective. You could show that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ you have $f(x) \geq 5$. Therefore the function can't be surjective.